# Can the arguments for CUDA kernel launch be dynamic?

Tags: cuda

i want to pass a random no. to the threads, 
like

```
main()
{
.
.
.

func<<<1,10>>(rand()%10);
.
.
.
}
```

is it possible to do that?

i am quite new to CUDA programming and I might have missed a crucial point here.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

(Note: your kernel call syntax isn't quite right: `func<<<1,10>>`, but I assume that's a typing error)

Comment: thank you very much...and lastly, will the device copy data from host ten times before launching the thread??

Comment: No, it behaves like an ordinary C function call.  The same parameters are available to each thread.